# Scanning for "Download: " in a list of strings with sentences

Tags: python, string, list

I have a script that gets the download and upload speeds of my internet. Now I am making a script that gathers all the download data from a txt file, and averages it, puts it in an excel spreadsheet, or other things. The problem is I haven't been able to find a way to scan for the "Download: " since there is also the download data in the string. I want to be able to get the indexes of all the strings with Download: in them and also get the data after that.

I tried using any() to scan for the words, but realized it just told me if the element is in the list and also that it only checked if the entire word "Download: " was in the list as a string.

```py
downloads_string = "Download: "
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    file.readlines()
    data_downloads_list = any(element in downloads_string for element in file)
    print(data_downloads_list)
```

I expected to get true, but always got false even tough I had Download: in my txt file. I realized it was scanning for strings that were simply "Download: " rather than strings that contained the word along with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file.readlines()` reads the lines of the file into a list and since it's never assigned to anything just gets garbage collected... you've also got the logic reversed (you're trying to check if your line is in the string you're looking for - not if the string you're looking for is in the line), try:

```
downloads_string = 'Download: '
with open('file.txt') as file:
    data_downloads_list = [line for line in file if downloads_string in line]
    print(data_downloads_list)
```

Comment: it works! But what exactly is going on at 
```py3
[line for line in file if downloads_string in line]
```

Comment: Ok so I looked at it more but i dont understand why you need the element "line" at the beggining of the for loop. I get that its doing, for every element in file, if element containts Download:, but i dont understand why theres a element reference at the beggining of the statement

Comment: @DucklingTurtle I'm guessing you're new to host list comprehensions work? Maybe have a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comprehensions-in-python/... What's on the left hand side can still have something before it gets applied to the output list other operations... so - one could do `[line.strip() + "I'VE GOT OUTPUT" for line in file if downloads_string in line]` for instance (the one in this answer is just using it for filtering rather than manipulating the final output of the list)